# Yii2 getters & setters to format string to float

Tags: php

Ok so currently have this function in controller, which is called multiple times.

```
public function formatFloat($value)
{
    return (float)sprintf('%0.6f', $value);
}
```

So I am trying to use getters and setters so I can just use

```
$model->$whatever;
```

and the formatting will be done.

In my model I have

```
public function getChargePeak()
{
    return $this->charge_peak;
}

public function setChargePeak($value)
{
    return $this->charge_peak = (float)sprintf('%0.6f', $value);
}
```

but when doing

```
 $peak = $model->chargepeak;
  var_dump($peak);die;
```

it is still returning as a string

Comment: which datatype is the charge_peak property ?

Comment: A string, trying to convert to float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the charge_peak property is stored as string and you need  a float in you app  you should  use

```
public function getChargePeak()
{
    return floatval($this->charge_peak);
 }
```

Anyway you should store the values in a coherent way as  you use the values in your app ..

http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

Comment: I've literally just solved it using:
 `public function getChargePeak()
    {
        return (float)sprintf('%0.6f', $this->charge_peak);
    }`

Comment: well ...  i suggest you the use of same type in db and php app

Comment: Your solution is cleaner so I'll accept that as the answer but both work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I suggest u another pattern: decorator and helpers. You should use a controller only to get data from request, prepare it for model and send it to view.

Formatting values is a helper logic. So create a new class 
\common\helpers\Number.php

```
namespace common\helpers;

class Number
{
    public static function formatFloat($value)
    {
        return (float)sprintf('%0.6f', $value);
    }
}
```

Then create decorator for your model:

```
namespace common\models\decorators;

class YourModelDecorator
{

    /**
     * YourModel
     */
    private $model;

    public function __construct(YourModel $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        $methodName = 'get' . $name;
        if (method_exists(self::class, $methodName)) {
            return $this->$methodName();
        } else {
            return $this->model->{$name};
        }
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        return $this->model->$name($arguments);
    }

    public function getChargePeak()
    {
        return \common\helpers\Number::formatFloat($this->model->charge_peak);
    }
}
```

and send it to view for example:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);

    $this->render('view', [
        'model' => new \common\models\decorators\YourModelDecorator($model)
    ]);
}
```